# GPUImageView stop responding to "Filter Change" after two times

Tags: ios, filter, gpuimage

I'm probably missing something. I'm trying to change filter to my `GPUImageView`.It's actually working the first two times(sometimes only one time), and than stop responding to changes. I couldn't find a way to remove the target from my `GPUImageView`.

Code

```
for x in filterOperations
        {
            x.filter.removeAllTargets()
        }
        let f = filterOperations[randomIntInRange].filter
        let media = GPUImagePicture(image: self.largeImage)
        media?.addTarget(f as! GPUImageInput)
        f.addTarget(g_View)
        media.processImage()
```

Any suggestions? * **Processing still image from my library**

**UPDATE**

Updated Code

```
//Global

var g_View: GPUImageView!
var media = GPUImagePicture()

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    media = GPUImagePicture(image: largeImage)
}

func changeFilter(filterIndex : Int)
{
    media.removeAllTargets()
    let f = returnFilter(indexPath.row) //i.e GPUImageSepiaFilter()
    media.addTarget(f as! GPUImageInput)
    f.addTarget(g_View)

    //second Part
    f.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
    let sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    imageSource.processImageWithCompletionHandler({
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
        return
    })

     dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
     let img =       f.imageFromCurrentFramebufferWithOrientation(img.imageOrientation)
     if img != nil
     {
     //Useable - update UI

     }
     else
     {
        //  Something Went wrong

     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My primary suggestion would be to not create a new GPUImagePicture every time you want to change the filter or its options that you're applying to an image. This is an expensive operation, because it requires a pass through Core Graphics and a texture upload to the GPU.

Also, since you're not maintaining a reference to your GPUImagePicture beyond the above code, it is being deallocated as soon as you pass out of scope. That tears down the render chain and will lead to a black image or even crashes. `processImage()` is an asynchronous operation, so it may still be in action at the time you exit your above scope.

Instead, create and maintain a reference to a single GPUImagePicture for your image, swap out filters (or change the options for existing filters) on that, and target the result to your GPUImageView. This will be much faster, churn less memory, and won't leave you open to premature deallocation.

Comment: Hey Brad! Thank you for the very detailed answer. I think i've made something like that. Tho i have noticed that if i "reuse" the same filter it does not react(the GPUImageView). Tho if re-create the filter and than calling processImage. It does changes and react everytime! Thanks Brad!

Comment: @RoiMulia - Make sure that the filter is properly connected to the GPUImagePicture and the GPUImageView before calling processImage(), which is what triggers the update propagation in the filter chain. Also, make sure you don't have any trailing references to the GPUImageView or from the GPUImagePicture from no-longer-used filters. These can lead to odd artifacts.

Comment: Thank you. Mind if i update the OS with my code(very short). Just to make sure i'm not making mistakes?

Comment: Hey Brad, Again thank you for your time. I've updated the code. I used the semaphore method because sometimes processImage returned nil(even in the completion), So i saw an issue about it over git and thats method actually working.

Comment: @RoiMulia - In the above, you're not removing the targets from the previous filter that was attached to the picture. Those will still be pointing at the view, and will lead to odd behavior. Make sure you remove those before you swap in a new filter. I honestly have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with the semaphore you're creating there. It won't actually do anything to synchronize the processing here.

Comment: Hey Brad. So basically it's fine to re-create filter, but i need to make sure to .RemoveAllTargets from the previous one? Secondly, I just got nil results from the processImage, so i entered this  https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1522  issue, and i tried multiple things, i have no exact clue what this code does - but untill now it's working.